# How to create a query to return results after comparing 2 sheets in Excel 2013

Tags: excel

I have two sheets. One lists Victims and the Other Suspects. On each sheet, a "Y" is placed in the cell that corresponds to the Date column when that person was present. I need to run a query of sorts which returns data onto an excel sheet. The data I need to return is 'When a Victim Column (victim sheet) and Suspect Column (suspect sheet) show "Y" on the same date row' return victim and suspect code and date

I am completely new to Excel and have no idea what term to search for to find a how to guide.

[Suspects Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFUw8.png)

[Victims Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMUkf.png)

Answer (score -1):

The below answer will create a third sheet with the same look (numbered columns along the top, dates along the left), filling in a Y in all those locations where victims and suspects each have a y in the same column/date. If that's not what you're after, please clarify and we can explore more complex solutions.

1. Add your dates and headers to a third sheet.
2. Place the following formula in cell B2 of the new sheet:

   =IF(AND(Suspects!B2="Y", Victims!B2="Y"), "Y", "")
3. Drag the formula across and down to fill in the rest of the table.

It works by simply verifying that there is a Y in both cells on both sheets. If it can, it returns a Y. If it can't, it returns nothing.